# Do terrain transformations and pillaging worsen AI attitude?

Tags: freeciv

I did these things to an AI player:

1. I transformed some of the AI's productive tiles into ocean tiles (to make a "canal").
2. I pillaged some roads and railroads to put a stop to direct attacks on my city.

Will these actions cause the AI attitude to worsen?